# Check if request is in state of re-direct

Tags: node.js, http, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

There is a way with express check if the request is in status redirect (302) ,I use the( req,res ) I use the following ?

```
var http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});   

proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    proxyReq.setHeader('X-Special-Proxy-Header', 'foobar');
});

proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {
    console.log('RAW Response from the target', JSON.stringify(proxyRes.headers, true, 2));
});
```

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Comment: Could you please clarify a) which request you want to check for 302 (`proxyReq` or `req`?), and b) where in your above code that should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but you can easily do the following:

```
proxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res) {     
    if (proxyRes.statusCode === 301 || proxyRes.statusCode === 302) {
        proxyRes.headers['location'] = fixUrl(proxyRes.headers['location']);
    }
});
```

Where `fixUrl()` does any necessary transform on the `location` response header.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for proxyRes event and check its status code (status code for redirection is 30x). ProxyRes is a raw response from your target, so you should be able to catch and modify the response headers before the proxy send this response to the client.

Alternatively, you can also set the proxy options that handle 30x redirects. Either setting the autoRewrite to true or explicitly state the location in the hostRewrite and protocolRewrite should do the trick. https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#options